# Edited Typescript Code in Type Towel not reflected in corresponding js file

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, durandal

I had Edited the Typescript code of home.ts in Type towel project downloaded from following URL:

https://github.com/Svakinn/TypeTowel/trunk/TypeTowel

I had just added a new variable in view model and tried to display it on my home page it does not reflect on home page. and also no reflected in the corresponding js file.

I am sharing my view model

old viewmodel:

```
 export class ViewModel {
    title: string = 'Home View';


    public activate() {
        _logger.logger.log('We are home now', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
}
export var vm = new ViewModel();

//The Durandal plugin-interface variables
export var activate = function () { return vm.activate(); };
```

new View model:

```
 export class ViewModel {
    title: string = 'Home View';
    titleS: string = "my view";

    public activate() {
        _logger.logger.log('We are home now', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
}
export var vm = new ViewModel();

//The Durandal plugin-interface variables
export var activate = function () { return vm.activate(); };
```

My Html line that I added to home.html is:

```
<span data-bind="text: vm.titleS"></span>
```

As I am new to type script please let me what is wrong that I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the TypeScript is not getting compiled in your app.
You should get the latest version of TypeTowel - where the typescript compile is no longer dependent on the Web Essentials plugin.